# How to turn off image tiling in the game engine?

Tags: texturing, game-engine

I was wondering how to turn off image tiling for textures in the game engine. My UV map would make it tile right now (i.e. it's bigger than the map), but I can't figure out how to turn tiling off. I'm using the game engine with GLSL enabled.

Comment: Just curious as pertaining my answer below. Your question is worded funny. Texture tiling and (tiling textures) can be interpreted as two different things.. please clarify exactly what you mean.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the UV Image Editor, bring up the properties toolshelf with <kbd>N</kbd> and under *Game Properties*, under the *Clamp* group, tick *X* and *Y*, you can now scale your map larger than your image without tiling your texture..

[image]

Comment: Is there something I need to do in the texture settings also? It's still tiling.

Comment: @CharlesL hmm.. this worked for me, you could try under texture settings, change *Image Mapping* to *Clip* and also make sure that your mesh is unwrapped properly (the default unwrap) and under *Mapping*, *Coordinates* is set to *UV*.

Comment: Ah, it was working before, it just wasn't updating. Changing the shading settings to singletexture then back to glsl updated it.